# jQuery .click() not firing as expecting

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to achieve is:

- User click h4 inside of a .question div
- .question div is expanded to 90px, and it's child paragraph slides into view by having its margin-top set to 0
- When the user clicks the h4 element a second time, the .question div should return to 35px height and the paragraph should have margin-top set to 35px.

**[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wnZG/1/)**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.question h4').click(function () {
        $(this).parents('.question').css('height', '90');
        $(this).siblings('p').css('margin-top', '0');
        $(this).parent().addClass('open');
    });

    $('.question.open h4').click(function () {
        $(this).parent.removeClass('open');
        $(this).parents('.question').css('height', '65px');
        $(this).siblings('p').css('margin-top', '35px');
    });
});
```

Comment: Typo? `$(this).parent` ?? Also check this http://api.jquery.com/end/ will help chain all those methods.

Comment: The first click event will always be applied to both cases! Use one handler and check for the state!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really just need one handler:

```
$('.question h4').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is('.open h4')) {
        $(this).parent.removeClass('open');
        $(this).parents('.question').css('height', '65px');
        $(this).siblings('p').css('margin-top', '35px');
    }
    else {
        $(this).parents('.question').css('height', '90');
        $(this).siblings('p').css('margin-top', '0');
        $(this).parent().addClass('open');
    }
});
```

Your second handler assignment does nothing because none of your `<h4>` elements start off with the "open" class (or, at least, I suspect they don't).

Comment: Wow. I don't know HOW I missed that... Thanks! I'm going to mark this as the answer since you pointed out why it wasn't firing.

Comment: @mchandleraz ok I made a minor fix just now to the `.is()` test

Answer (score 4):

Your first click handler is firing even if `.question` is `.open`. You need to exclude `.open` from the first selector.

```
$('.question:not(.open) h4').click(...
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  How will the ".open" handler work for all the `<h4>` elements that start off without the ".open" class?

Comment: None of this makes sense. You need to bind to all elements, then check if they have the class or not...or use event delegation, but that's really unnecessary. Keeping the way the OP did it, binding to two different selectors (even if you "fix" the selectors), will not work

Answer (score 2):

As Pointy mentioned, you only need 1 handler with a conditional statement.  Also, for speed, overhead, and simplicity, I would consider stringing all desired action on a node into one line (i.e., anything you want to do with a $(this).parent() should be stringed together so jQuery only has to parse the DOM one time).

```
$('.question h4').click(function () {
    if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('open')){
        $(this).parents('.question').css('height', '90').addClass('open');
        $(this).siblings('p').css('margin-top','0');
    }else{
        //$(this).parents('.question').css('height', '65px');
        $(this).parent().css('height', '65px').removeClass('open');
        $(this).siblings('p').css('margin-top', '35px');
    }
});
```

Comment: This is something I've known that I was doing wrong for a while, but hadn't bothered to figure out the proper way to do things. Thanks for the info. I'll be re-writing quite a bit of my jQuery shortly :)